# Google App Engine Java - Keep Session alive after users close browser (remember me function)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, remember-me

We can enable session by setting sessions-enabled to true in file appengine-web.xml. However, the session implemented by GAE is not persistent after closing browsers. My question is how to keep the session persistent so "remember me" function can be implemented. There are a number of Python libraries but I couldn't find any for Java. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

The common way to do this is to associate a unique random key to your users, store it in a persistent cookie (use `Cookie.setMaxAge()` with the number of seconds you want this cookie to stay valid), and send this cookie to the user.

Look in the javadoc for `HttpServletResponse.addCookie` (to send a cookie to the user), and for `HttpServletRequest.getCookies()` (to get back the cookie from the client).

Comment: I know how to set and get cookies on client side. My question is that how to tell App Engine (on server) that we want it to retrieve a session with a specified ID (get this value from cookie), and not generating a new session every time we close browser and reopen it.

Comment: GAE stored the session state in the datastore, in the _ah_SESSION kind. AFAIK, they're not cleaned up automatically (yet), so you could cheat with the session mechanism by setting a very long expiration delay, and set the JSESSIONID cookie yourself, with a non-zero max age.

Comment: Great, you solved my problem! I set a cookie with a different name (sid, not JSESSIONID), that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Since we can't mark a comment as an answer (and some people are likely to miss it entirely), I'll point out the specific solution per JB above. Get the session id using `this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getId()`. Store the sid in a cookie as `JSESSIONID` with Cookies.setCookie(...)

This overwrites the cookie created by GAE, keeping the same session id, but applying your expiration time. Be careful how you use this, though, it's prone to attacks (look up session hijacking and XSS).

Comment: That didnt work for me when I used a servlet filter. When I inspected the response the JSESSIONID cookie hadnt been added yet, implying it is added afterwards? I created mine with maxage-1 but it came back to browser with two JSESSIONIDs in the header and just a session expiry

Comment: ..implying GAE added the cookie after me, blatting the expiry